# Add-in suddenly missing from Office Add-in Store on Mac Word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, office-store

Our word add-in seems to have been removed from the Mac Microsoft store. It was working for over a year and then on Saturday (Feb 29, 2020) it was removed only from the Office Add-on store for Mac clients of Word only. The issue can be reproduced by opening Word for Mac and searching for our add-in (“SmartCite for Papers”) in the Office Store.  No results are returned, however if you do the same search on Word for Windows or Word Online, our add-in appears.

Our manifest file on the portal supports Mac:
[image: Portal.Manifest]
The word add-in was working on Mac, PC, and word online.

If you inspect the traffic to the Office API, it appears the Word client version is returning different responses.  Here’s an example search with client=Mac_Word which returns 0 results:
https://store.office.com/api/addins/search?ad=US&apiversion=1.0&client=Mac_Word&clientsessionid=3ed6cccc-232f-43d5-9044-fb66aabbbe02&corr=4613ec1c-35a4-43a7-a3f8-ac4f2618bab9&cv=16.0&free=false&orderby=Desc&orderfield=None&qu=smartcite&rs=en-US&skiptoitem=0&top=15&ui=en-US

Doing the same search for the Online Word client (client=WAC_Word) returns our extension:
https://store.office.com/api/addins/search?ad=US&apiversion=1.0&client=WAC_Word&clientsessionid=3ed6cccc-232f-43d5-9044-fb66aabbbe02&corr=4613ec1c-35a4-43a7-a3f8-ac4f2618bab9&cv=16.0&free=false&orderby=Desc&orderfield=None&qu=smartcite&rs=en-US&skiptoitem=0&top=15&ui=en-US

We are trying to determine why the Office Store is not returning our app to Mac clients suddenly as of Feb 29, 2020.

The only change we have made recently was to submit an app update to the Office Store on Partner Center on Feb 17th.  That submission has not been released yet (status remains “In Progress”), though it was “certified” on Feb 28th.

We paid to open a priority support ticket with Microsoft Support and was informed that Office Store issues can only be supported on Stack Overflow.  We hope someone on the Office Store team can look into why our application has been removed from the Mac store and advise what we can do to restore it.

Our add-in is called SmartCite for Papers and its ID is [WA104380917](https://store.office.com/api/addins/search?ad=US&apiversion=1.0&client=WAC_Word&clientsessionid=3ed6cccc-232f-43d5-9044-fb66aabbbe02&corr=4613ec1c-35a4-43a7-a3f8-ac4f2618bab9&cv=16.0&free=false&orderby=Desc&orderfield=None&qu=smartcite&rs=en-US&skiptoitem=0&top=15&ui=en-US).

Comment: We (Microsoft) are investigating this problem and we hope to have it fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting Jacob (and Ricky!) - we're investigating this now.

Comment: @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms Please note that this question is off-topicf on StackOverflow and should be closed/deleted.

Comment: @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms As per the tag-wiki "Questions asking about the store's terms & conditions or seeking customer service are off-topic."

Comment: @Jacob - this should be resolved now. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms would you mind having a look at (and perhaps commenting on) this question? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394024/burninate-office-store-tag